# reactjs -- Want to create an "Add" button that adds a new row for inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a page that has 3 rows of user inputs at first. It'll look like

email          role               group

[text input]   [dropdown list]    [dropdown list]

[text input]   [dropdown list]    [dropdown list]

[text input]   [dropdown list]    [dropdown list]

where text input would be a inputfield for user to add emails. The dropdown list is simply a dropdown block

I want to create a button that can add another row of this. So far, each row is in a `NewUser` component that looks like

```
<div className='new-user'>
    <label className="email-input">
        <input type="text" name="email"/>
    </label>
    <Dropdown className='dropdown' options={roles} onChange={this._onSelect} value={defaultRoleOption} placeholder="Select a role"/>
    <Dropdown className='dropdown' options={groups} onChange={this._onSelect} value={defaultGroupOption} placeholder="Select a group"/>
</div>
```

`roles` & `groups` are arrays

I don't know what's the best way to do this. I can create a `rowNum` which I can store in `state`, then every time I click the button, it increments this number, but I don't know how to make react populate # of rows based on this number.

Or maybe there's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

nevermind I got it.

```
let rowNum=3;
let newUserList = [];
for (let i=0; i<this.state.rowNum; i++) {
            newUserList.push(<NewUser roles={this.state.roles} datasets={this.state.datasets}/>);
        }
return (
      <div>
            {newUserList}
      </div>

    );
```

This works. but is it not as efficient compare to using `map`?